# How to fill in template text file based off of user input using HTML/PHP/JAVA?

Tags: java, php, html, forms

I have a long and complex text based config file for a tool that sometimes requires changes to be made. Rather than asking users to edit this config file themselves, I want to have a config file template to be populated based off of user input on a HTML web form, and provide the file to the user via download. I'm new to HTML/PHP, I'm not even sure what the best way to go about this is. I've successfully been able to grab user input and store the data into variables for what needs to be changed in the template file, I just don't know how to get that data into my template txt file.

I need to get whatever the user inputs into the appropriate place in my config file as seen below.

**Sample User Input from HTML Form**

```
$userInput = "bravo"
```

**Sample Config**

```
set option1 "alpha"
set option2 $profileChoice
set option3 "charlie"
set option4 $team
```

How can I generate a file for a user, based off of a template, and provide it for download?

**EDIT**

Here is my sample index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p>Choose your team and options.</p>

<form action="make.php" method="POST">
  <label for="team">Choose a team:</label>
  <select name="team" id="team">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" id="profile1" name="profileChoice" value="profile1">
  <label for="profile1">Profile1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="profile2" name="profileChoice" value="profile2">
  <label for="profile2">Profile2</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="profile3" name="profileChoice" value="profile3">
  <label for="profile3">Profile3</label>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my make.php

```
<html>
<body>
<p>TEST</p>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$team = $_POST["team"];
$profileChoice = $_POST["profileChoice"];
echo "<p> Your team was: $team </p>";
echo "<p> Your profile was: $profileChoice </p>";
?>
```

My data gets passed to the second page and is visable, but as for how to insert values into template text files and give it to the user, I'm stuck.

Comment: What is the "template text file" and how do you want to "Give it to the user"?

Comment: The template text file is the 'Sample Config' listed above.
I just want to subsititute the values and force a download onto the user when complete.